# .htaccessで原則httpはhttpsにリダイレクトですが、一部のURLは除いてhttpアクセスできるようにしたいです。

Tags: php, cakephp, apache, .htaccess

cakephp2.3.5でwebサイトを構築しており、.htaccessの設定で外部からのアクセスは原則httpsで統一したいのですが、一部のURLはhttpアクセスしたいです。

以下のURLをhttpでも許可したい場合、下記コードですとurlを認識せず、httpsリダイレクトされてしまいます。
http://example.co.jp/test1/test2?no=1234

```
# index.php無しに統一
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.(html|htm|php)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(html|htm|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.(html|htm|php)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(html|htm|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# CakePHP用
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(#*.*)$ index.php?url=$1$2 [QSA,L]

#################################################################
# 今回のhttp→httpsを追加
#################################################################
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/test1/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

.htaccessはproject/app/webroot/.htaccessを編集しております。

正規表現がよろしくないのでしょうか？
または他の設定の影響など。

また、.htaccessのデバッグを出せるようにしたのですが、RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/test1/)の判定など通常出ているのでしょうか？いまいちログを追えていない状態です。

参考サイト
http://qiita.com/gotohiro55/items/7daa988db23a5a8355c1
https://kana-lier.com/web/redirect/
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shimonoakio/20080226/1204089340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純に記述順が間違っています。

各RewriteRuleには `L` フラグがついているため、条件にマッチした場合そこで書換を終了します。

RewriteRule Flags - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

つまり、例示の.htaccessでは、ファイル／ディレクトリが存在しない場合はCakePHPのルールに該当するため、以降のルールは無視されることになります。

順序を変えて以下のようにするとよいでしょう。

```
# index.php無しに統一
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.(html|htm|php)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(html|htm|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.(html|htm|php)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(html|htm|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#################################################################
# 今回のhttp→httpsを追加
#################################################################
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/test1/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# CakePHP用
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(#*.*)$ index.php?url=$1$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。順序を変えましたら良い方向に動きました。実際のファイルはもっと記述があるのですが、ご指摘通り、記述の順序が影響してそうです。あとは調べてみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

設定は合っていると思います。
デバッグログを出すには、httpd.conf に下記例のように設定ください。

```
(httpd-2.2)
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 4
  # 0 - 9

(httpd-2.4)
  LogLevel warn rewrite:trace4
  # trace1 - trace8, error_log に出力される
```

Answer (score 1):

`/test1/`以下のURIを対象外にするのであれば、RewriteCondの2行目はこうではないでしょうか?
(質問の記載だと、URIが`/test1/`の場合のみ対象外になるように見えます)

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/test1/.*$)
```

ちなみに、`http`アクセスを表すのであれば、ポート番号よりも、参考サイト( http://qiita.com/gotohiro55/items/7daa988db23a5a8355c1 )にあるように、`%{HTTPS}`で判定した方が厳密かと思います。

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。うまくいかなかったのですが、RewriteRuleの記述にも問題ありますかね。

Answer (score 1):

合ってそうに見えますね。
当てずっぽうで書くと `^` を括弧で挟むのは 違和感があるので次のようにすると動作変わったりしませんか？

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/test1/)
```

もしくは

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test1/
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。やはりhttpsでリダイレクトされてしまいます。色んなパターンで調べてみます。

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさんの回答にあるように、Rewriteのログを取得して、質問に追記してもらえれば、何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: REQUEST_URIでなく、%{THE_REQUEST} !^/test1/　でできました。やはりログでパラメータの中身見なきゃだめですね。